# cursor:default being inserted into anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link that does not turn to a pointer on hover.  My html looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" ><a name="linkInstructions" id="linkInstructions"
   href="javascript:clickYesNo('linkInstructions');">#session.surveyRb.instructions#</a>  
  </td>
</tr>
```

It looks the same when the source is viewed on the browser.  However, when inspecting the element, the code inserts the style attribute.
    
    Instructions
I know this is not a stylesheet issue, but I am confused to how the `style="cursor:default;"` is getting inserted.

Comment: Link to the page, please?

Comment: Since we can only guess... Perhaps there's some Javascript that's doing it.

Comment: You are right.  It was included in a piece of JavaScript code. Javascript must take precedence over inline html and CSS because it is loaded last?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pointer by setting

```
cursor: pointer;
```

to that element in you CSS.

If you provide a link to your website or piece of code I can gladly help you to find out what is interupting its normal behaviour.